# Running class java stored on server, locally

Tags: java, browser, applet

Is there any way to execute (locally) a java class stored on server, without actually downloading it to the HD?

My intention is that once the user has loaded the website on his browser, he will not have to be connected to the internet in order to execute it. That way the server will not know the arguments which the class interface has.

Comment: You can make use of Applets.

Comment: Thank you! I will study it and maybe use it. I think it will work out for me (from what i've read until now). Thanks again :), if you post it as an answer, I'll be glad to accept...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your requirement to run java on client side. I think Applet will be best suitable for the scenario.

Read more about Java [Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this situation is a free floating applet or frame deployed using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) that specifies `offline-allowed`.  Desktop shortcuts can be installed for launching the app. on later occasions.